# Bash - is it possible to use ${##} to remove substring from command result?

Tags: bash

I supposed this would give me name of current branch in git.

```
echo "${`git symbolic-ref HEAD`##refs/heads}"
```

However, it results in

```
-bash: ${`git symbolic-ref HEAD`##refs/heads}: bad substitution
```

Is it possible to use ## on command result on a single line without storing the result in an intermediate variable, or do I have to use other means like `sed`?

Comment: can u share the result of `git symbolic-ref HEAD` and your expected result...

Comment: `bash` does not allow such a substitution to happen. The expansions happen on a variable content

Comment: try this, `echo "` ` `git symbolic-ref HEAD` ` `##refs/heads"`

Answer (score 2):

Not with `bash`,  but you could with `zsh`:

```
printf '%s\n' "${$(git symbolic-ref HEAD)#refs/heads}"
```

would work there.

Or you could always do the stripping with `sed`:

```
printf '%s\n' "$(git symbolic-ref HEAD | sed '1s|^refs/heads||')"
```

It would get more complicated if the part to strip contained newline characters. For instance, if the part to strip was `$'1\n2\n3\n'`, you'd need something like:

```
cmd1 -- "$(cmd2 | sed '1{$!N;$!N;$!N; s/^1\n2\n3\n//;}')"
```

So you might as well use a temporary variable which also has the benefit of preserving `cmd2`'s exit status:

```
strip=$'1\n2\n3\n'

out=$(cmd2); cmd2_status=$?
cmd1 -- "${out#"$strip"}"
```

Answer (score 0):

No, I'm afraid that is not possible because the `##` idiom belongs to *variable* expansion only, thus you always have to refer to an existing variable.

However, for your case you might like the following hack:

```bsh
sh -c 'echo "${*##refs/heads}"' - "`git symbolic-ref HEAD`"
```

or: (*as a better Bashism*)

```bsh
sh -c 'echo "${*##refs/heads}"' -- "$(git symbolic-ref HEAD)"
```

This runs a non-interactive `sh` with the output from your `git` command as its argument, on which it then uses the `##` idiom.

If you can trust your command's output to be sanitized enough (ie not containing `*` or other glob characters) you can save yourself to type the double-quotes.